# How to wrap "Read More" link in a DIV tag?

Tags: excerpt, read-more

Can someone tell me how to wrap the Read More anchor (that displays after an excerpt) with DIV tags using `get_the_content('Read More')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put a filter on [`the_content_more_link`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/post-template.php#L217).

Untested but...

```
function wrap_more_link($more) {
    return '<div>'.$more.'</div>';
}
add_filter('the_content_more_link','wrap_more_link');
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this on all my themes. pretty similar to the answer above This will add a permalink to the the "more" text . You can also add div and style it accordingly. Hope this helps

```
function more_excerpt($more) {
       global $post;
  return '&nbsp; &nbsp;><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"><div> Change Read more text here</div></a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'more_excerpt');
```